# Is there a function like "bcadd" except it performs multiplication?

Tags: php

I'm hoping to do some math operations on numbers being represented as strings.  So far, I haven't found anything that could do multiplication.

Thanks!

Comment: Seriously? You didn't think of just replacing `add` with `mul`? You know, I bet there's a `bcsub` and `bcdiv` as well, without even looking. Actually, I did have a quick look since I didn't want to sound stupid in case I was wrong :-) For example, if there was no `bcsub` because `bcadd` handled negatives just fine. But there is, so I don't sound stupid. Well, no stupider than normal :-)

Comment: I tried bcmult but not bcmul *facepalm*. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need of the [`bcmul()`](http://br.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.bcmul.php) method. You too can take a look on [`BC Math`](http://br.php.net/manual/pt_BR/ref.bc.php) functions.

**Example**:

```
echo bcmul('2.123456', '4.7891011', 6); // 6 is the precision
```

Answer (score 0):

You mean [bcmul](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.bcmul.php)?

Answer (score 0):

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.bcmul.php

> bcmul — Multiply two arbitrary precision number
>
> string bcmul ( string $left_operand , string $right_operand [, int $scale ] )
>
> Multiply the left_operand by the right_operand.